# Aggregate many records into each result from a second mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have an 'events' table and 'photos' table. Each event may have zero or many records that correspond to it in the 'photos' table. The following sql gives me a separate result for each event.

How can I aggregate the photos into a single field for an event so that each result is a unique event and the photos are accessible from something like $event['photos'] in php?

```
SELECT e.title, e.eid, p.pid
FROM events e
RIGHT JOIN photos p ON p.aeid = e.eid
WHERE e.dateTimeStart >= $start_date_time AND e.dateTimeStart <= $end_date_time
```

Comment: I think you have to do some iterating in your resultset so you can arrange that... but it has to be done by processing the output resultset in php.

Comment: bummer, that's what I have in production but it's getting sluggish with many event records. edit: well, i'm doing a separate photos query for each event.  i'll see if processing this output speeds things up (was hoping to do it all in sql though)

Comment: If you want to improve performance, you can try adding an index on photos like (aeid DESC, pid ASC). This will improve the speed of the queries by aeid on photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using MySql, you have the option of using the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function:

```
SELECT e.title, e.eid, GROUP_CONCAT(p.pid) AS pids
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN photos p ON p.aeid = e.eid
WHERE e.dateTimeStart >= $start_date_time AND e.dateTimeStart <= $end_date_time
GROUP BY e.title, e.eid
```

However, remember that storing multiple values in a single column violates first normal form... so weigh this against your other concerns before using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function... and never *store* your data in this form.

Also, note that the `RIGHT JOIN` changed to a `LEFT JOIN`... which is not only preferred for asthetic reasons, I think it is the functionality that you want since `events` is the required row, and `photos` can be `zero to many`.